# How to project a point to wgs84 crs with geographicLib

Tags: java, projection, wgs84, geographic-lib

In my app I use a specific framework with Low-level methods that converts projected coordinates back to longitude and latitude from `crs` `WGS84`.

However, I then need to re-project these absolute values of the point with `GeographicLib`.

How can I take the given absolute lat long and project it to the `crs` `wgs84`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that the `GeographicLib` performs geographic conversions and transformations but it does not include projection to a specific `CRS`. To project a point to a specific `CRS` we can use a projection library e.g. `Proj4`.